# Finding the location of defined JavaScript using Firebug or alternative tool

Tags: javascript, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

I am attempting to locate where a particular class/function/object is defined on a site with many javascripts being rendered. Manually sifting through the scripts has proven to be very time consuming in the 'Scripts' panel of Firebug.

Before I continue going that route, is there an easier way using modern front-end development tools to locate where certain things are defined? Would be great if I had some kind of ctags type functionality that vim provides, but any other approach would be great.

Comment: I'd like to know this, too. It would be especially handy when answering SO questions, since I don't know what's going on in the questioner's site.

Comment: What do you mean by "class"? A function?

Comment: I've edited my question. class/function/object, whatever. If someone even has a simple object definition of a = {}; and later uses a.bar = "foo", I'd love to be able to go back to find what file the a in current scope was defined in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome has Find in all Sources:

CTRL-SHIFT-F on Windows and CMD-OPT-F on Mac.

Edit:

You can also use CMD-SHIFT-O (mac) CTRL-SHIFT-O (windows/linux) in chrome to find functions by name.

[image]

Comment: In Firebug you can search via [`Ctrl+F`/`⌘+F`](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Keyboard_and_Mouse_Shortcuts#Global).

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK none of the standard dev tools (Chrome Debugger, Firebug, etc.) offer this functionality.  You can *sort of* get it by typing the object's name in the Chrome debugger, but that will just show you something like "Backbone.View.extend.extend.constructor".  In other words, it shows you the root-most constructor, which is fine if all your classes are exactly one level deep.  If not though, for instance if A is a subclass of B and B is a subclass of C, knowing that your object "a" comes from C doesn't really help much.

Furthermore, even if it is what you want, Chrome won't tell you where to find the constructor, just its name.  Personally I solve this by giving all my objects a `_type` property (or attribute, for the ones that are Backbone models).  This way I can simply type `myObject._type` (or `myObject.get('_type'`) for the models) and know what kind of object I have.  And since I give every object type a unique name, all it takes to find the cunstructor is `grep` for that name.

Comment: Thanks for this information. I suppose the problem is, I see an attribute being used over and over and I cannot find where there was an assignment made to it. It's a site's source that I don't own, which makes it even worse.

Comment: Right. None of the tools does let you jump from a function call or a variable usage to it's definition at the moment. I created an [issue for Firebug](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=2856) covering this a while back.